# What does the symbol ~ do in latex?

Tags: latex

This code :

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \large
        \textit{Author}\\
        B.J. \textsc{Blazkowicz} % Your name
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~% THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO KNOW
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \large
        \textit{Supervisor}\\
        Dr. Caroline \textsc{Becker} % Supervisor's name
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

produces
[image]

And this code

```
...
B.J. \textsc{Blazkowicz} % Your name
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~% THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO KNOW
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \large
...
```

produces [image]

How does that work? Does it like lock the minipages to the borders?

Comment: The `~` is a non-breaking space

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] for your second code block? Normally the `~` shouldn't be necessary as your two minipages sum up to `.8\textwidth` which does not yet cause a line break.